# List git tags excluding word in title

Tags: git, glob

I need to delete all of my tags excluding ones that end with "AppStore" word.
I know that I can delete tags with filtering by word like this:

`git tag -d $(git tag -l "1.158*")`

But I can't figure out how to make an exclude pattern.
I tried this:

`git tag -l "!*AppStore"`

This pattern works well in digital ocean glob test tool: [shorturl.at/yOR69](http://shorturl.at/yOR69) but terminal returns nothing.

I also tried this:

`git tag -l "!(*AppStore)"`

`git tag -l "*!(AppStore)"`

But result was the same.

Does anyone know how to accomplish this task right?

Comment: why not something with a pipe? Like `git tag | grep 'AppStore$' | xargs git tag -d`

Comment: But this will delete all tags containing 'AppStore' not excluding...
And I actually tried this `git tag | grep '^((?!AppStore).)*$'` - it also returns empty result

Comment: @AlexSh.: `grep -P '^((?!AppStore).)*$'` ?

Comment: Och right, so `grep -v 'AppStore$'`

Comment: @Inian, it returns `usage: grep [-abcDEFGHhIiJLlmnOoqRSsUVvwxZ] [-A num] [-B num] [-C[num]]
 [-e pattern` and so on

Comment: @KamilCuk nice! that `grep -v 'AppStore$'` did the trick!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to do many things in one go - it's easier to do small parts separately and join them. Try first listing all tags, then filtering the list, then removing the tags.

```
git tag | grep -v 'AppStore$' | xargs git tag -d
```

Comment: And to remove tags from remote firstly I should make
`git tag | grep -v 'AppStore$' | xargs git push -d origin`